# Cassandra migration data to new server

Tags: database, cassandra, centos, migration

How I can migrate data from Cassandra 3.9 (centos 6.7) to Cassandra 3.11 (centos 7).

I have one server where I have all the data. Unfortunately, I have to go to the new Cassandra 3.11 and the new Linux (Centos 7). How can I transfer/move data?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have all your data on one server - e.g. a single node cluster?

Simply copy over all your Cassandra files to the new server (`/var/lib/cassandra` for example, use some tool like `rsync`), install Cassandra 3.11 over it, look over the cassandra.yml to have the correct settings.

Start your new Cassandra instance and you should be done.

Comment: that right I have single node cluster.

Really I have to only copy all files from /var/lib/cassandra ?

Comment: So i have one more question. I should create keyspace after or befor copying files ?

Comment: You should not need to. All relevant infomation is stored in the keyspaces. Just copy the entire directory and config :)

Comment: It's not working. During start Cassandra i get a lot of WARN - Nodes X have the same token... or changing ownership token. Any solve ?

Comment: /var/lib/cassandra I moved. WARN I do not have anymore but the database is empty.

Comment: You did not shutdown the old node right? If you do not want to you need to setup a bew cluster (different name) and create the keyspaces and tables (describe keyspaces gives you a script) and then only copy your keyspace directories and not the system*.

Comment: Now I got Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='... Any idea ?

Comment: can you post the output of `nodetool status`?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.0.187  4,18 GiB   256          100,0%            81010700-a09a-4f2e-a5b2-581879c9fec3  rack1